# Rserve Exception "eval failed, request status: error code: 127"

Tags: java, r

I tried to execute some r code from java using Rserve:

```
try {
    RConnection conn = new RConnection();
    conn.eval("write.csv(PoS, file = 'C:/test/PoS.csv',row.names=FALSE)");
} catch (REngineException eR) {
    System.err.println("Exception: "+ eR);
    throw new TestException("syntax error on eval on R code");        
} catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw new TestException("parseAndEval did not generate an exception on syntax error" );    
}
```

I got the eval failed error. But I can successfully execute the Rcode in R:

```
write.csv(PoS, file = 'C:/test/PoS.csv',row.names=FALSE)
```

I am sure that `Rserve()` has been started on the R side, and other statements like

```
conn.eval("iris");
```

is possible.

Comment: @Kevin yes, File path is correct

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue. The matrix `PoS` need to be reloaded, every time I establish a new Rconnection, or save it in the default workspace image alternatively.

Answer (score 1):

To get the proper error message, use this instead of simple eval

```
REXP rResponseObject = rServeConnection.parseAndEval("try(eval("+R_COMMAND_OR_SOURCE_FILE_PATH+"),silent=TRUE)");
 if (rResponseObject.inherits("try-error")) { 
LOGGER.error("R Serve Eval Exception : "+rResponseObject.asString()); 
}
```

This logger prints exact error thrown from R.